# RequireJS - Do I have to reimport previously required files for child class

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

While I developing with requirejs and backbonejs, I got confused with how the import mechanism works, as I thought the imported class only applies to that functional scope. However, when I try to debug, I found out for some requirejs classes that I didn't import jquery or backbone or underscore, it still able to work properly, but this does not applies to other classes I created.

The below example illustrate what I meant:

1) index.html   -> initial load file

2) init.js -> importing all required classes and output whether the class is available

3) base.js  -> base class, importing all required libraries

4) shop.js  -> extend from base class, didn't not import jquery,backbone files, but it is working

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script data-main='init' src='http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.0.4/minified/require.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    halo world
</body>
</html>
```

init.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min',
        underscore: 'http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min', 
        backbone: 'http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min'
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },

        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});

require([
    'views/shop',
],function(ShopView){   
    var shopView = new ShopView();
    shopView.render();  

    console.log('Backbone - ');
    console.log(Backbone);
    console.log('Underscore - ');
    console.log(_);
    console.log('jQuery - ');
    console.log($);
    console.log('BaseView - ');
    console.log(BaseView);
});
```

shop.js

```
define([
    'views/base'
], function(BaseView) { 
    var ShopView = BaseView.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('ShopView');        
        }
    });
    return ShopView;
});
```

base.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'  
], function($,_,Backbone) { 
    var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('BaseView');        
        }
    });
    return BaseView;
});
```

The result output from init.js:

console.log(Backbone); -> returns me backbone classes even I didn't import it

console.log($); -> returns me jquery classes even I didn't import it

console.log(_); -> returns me underscore classes even I didn't import it

console.log(BaseView); -> returns undefined for my custom classes

If I remove views/shop from init.js.

```
require([

],function(){   
    console.log('Backbone - ');
    console.log(Backbone);
    console.log('Underscore - ');
    console.log(_);
    console.log('jQuery - ');
    console.log($);
    console.log('BaseView - ');
    console.log(BaseView);
});
```

console.log(Backbone); -> Undefined

console.log($); -> break

console.log(_); -> break

console.log(BaseView); -> break

I couldn't explain how previous scenario works, I thought backbone, jquery, underscore is global variables, but it seems I remove the view class, then the variables goes undefined, while if it is imported class, I could bring forward my previous imported class from base.js to future imported class. Sorry if it confused.

Can someone shed some lights on how the import in requirejs works and the scope of import. Do I have to re-require classes I previously required.

Answer (score 0):

require.config it's not importing anything by its own.
It is used for declaring alias (paths) and dependencies of non-AMD files.

Take in consideration that when you use 'define' , you are actually *requiring* its dependencies.

```
define ([ array of dependencies ], function)
```

.

```
init: require shop  (ok, let's bring shop here:
shop: require base  (ok, let's bring base here:
base: require    (so you need backbone, underscore and jquery.. ok,  
                  I'll bring them for you)
```

Then, when every dependency is required and loaded, the `init` execution starts.

When you remove `shop` from `init.js,` you are not requiring anything. Again **require.config doesn't import anything.**

PS. This is personal taste, but
I like more to have a file app.js where jquery,underscore and backbone are required. And then every module requires 'app'. It's also useful to share that namespace in case you want to add functions to it. (`app.myFunction`)

See this backbone poilerplate: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate

Comment: thanks, but why jquery, backbone and underscore is accessible even without importing it.

Comment: You're welcome. Even you don't use the word 'require', you are actually importing them when declaring the array of dependencies inside 'define'.
I think that's what confuses you. That 'define' can import things too. Let me know if it's not clear .